# tornado single thread server status page

Tags: html, ajax, nginx, tornado

currently, my tornado server is running in single thread mode because I just want a user at a time. the problem is when another user want to access, it just stuck there. I would like to give a message that "server is busy, please revisit later". what is the best way to do it?  I am thinking about ngix but I dont know how to do it

Comment: Can you provide the single-threaded source code you mention, or at least the gist of it?
In short: the code needs to be asynchronous in Tornado ioloop. Or, as you tagged nginx, you can set it up to show your page instead of nginx's 502 page.